# Scrollview with button(s) that can appear and disappear on tap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have created a scrollview, to scroll through an array of images, and I have a button and soon to be 6 more on the screen. Now to make the photo nicer, I would simply like to make the buttons disappear and when tapped on again to appear.

Now I know how to do this with just a regular view with simple isHidden, and how to make it reappear when tapped on, but I am largely confused on how to do it on a scrollview because on a regular view, I just put a button over the whole screen but with the scrollview I can't. Any ideas anyone? Still getting better at this one step at a time, and one question at a time.

Here is a screenshot: [http://imgur.com/a/Ll6QO](https://imgur.com/a/Ll6QO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a gesture recognizer on the scrollview.
Add a touch gesture recognizer to toggle the visibility of your buttons.  Be sure that the gesture recognizer doesn't cancel touches in view, otherwise you won't be able to scroll.